# How to SQL Merge when I need to match two columns

Tags: sql

I have a target table that have UserId, ItemId, and SomeData. I have a source table that I want to use to update the target based on missing ItemId.

Maybe easier explained in an example...

This is the target and the existing data:

```
UserId  ItemId  SomeData
1       1       x
2       2       y
2       3       z
```

And I have another temporary source table that holds some ItemId for a particular user. If that UserId already have that ItemId, ignore. If not there, add it.

```
UserId  ItemId  SomeData
1       1       x       <--- this ItemId already exist for UserId=1, ignore
1       2       a       <--- the next two ItemId don't exist for UserId=1, add them
1       3       b
```

Result set I'm expecting is like this:

```
UserId  ItemId  SomeData
    1       1       x
    2       2       y
    2       3       z
    1       2       a   <--- added
    1       3       b   <--- added
```

I'm struggling with the proper way to join the table within the merge command so that I can insert the missing ItemId records for the User.

```
MERGE Target T
USING Source S
ON T.UserId = S.UserId   --This doesn't get the right matches but neither does joining it by ItemId
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN 
    INSERT bah bah bah
```

How can I do that?

Comment: If you care about `Userid` and `Itemid`, just add them both to your `ON` section: `T.UserId = S.UserId AND T.ItemID = S.ItemID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO @tb AS T 
USING @tmpTb AS S 
    ON T.userId = S.userId AND T.itemId = S.itemId
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (userId, itemId, someData) 
    VALUES (S.userId, S.itemId , S.someData);
```

Here @tb is target table and @tmpTb is source table.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `ItemId` to the condition

```
MERGE Target T
USING Source S
ON (T.UserId = S.UserId AND T.ItemId = S.ItemId)
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN 
    INSERT bah bah bah
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you...By using UNION you can merge two tables without any duplicates .In case of using UNION ALL duplicates will also exist.

```
insert into Result_Table
    select UserId,ItemId,SomeData from table_one
    union
    select UserId,ItemId,SomeData from table_two
```